# Facing issues in Chat Pagination

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I am running the code to load the chats in swift iOS chat application. The problem in chat application is at "query in else{}" in function paginateData() while running the app, the first "query in if{}" runs smoothly as expected, but in other one does not run. I am using firestore database for implementing chat. 
My goal is to paginate the chats in the chat room. If any more information is required, please let me know.

CODE

```
func paginateData() {
    fetchingMore = true
    var query: Query!

    if messages.isEmpty {
        query = Firestore.firestore().collection("messageRoom").document(messageRoomIdFinal).collection("messages").order(by: "timestamp", descending: false).limit(to: 20)
        print("First 20 Messages loaded")
    } else {
        query = Firestore.firestore().collection("messageRoom").document(messageRoomIdFinal).collection("messages").order(by: "timestamp", descending: false).start(afterDocument: lastDocumentSnapshot).limit(to: 7)
        print("Next 7 Messages loaded")
    }

    query.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("\(err.localizedDescription)")
        } else if snapshot!.isEmpty {
            self.fetchingMore = false
            return
        } else {
            snapshot!.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                if (diff.type == .added) {
                    let snap = diff.document
                    let aMessage = Message(withSnap: snap)
                    self.messages.append(aMessage)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
                        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
                    }
                }

                if (diff.type == .modified) {
                    let docId = diff.document.documentID
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
                        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
                    }
                    //update the message with this documentID in the array
                }

                if (diff.type == .removed) {
                    let docId = diff.document.documentID
                    //remove the message with this documentID from the array
                }

                self.lastDocumentSnapshot = snapshot!.documents.last
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to format your code so it's readable. You've also got a typo `.collectioncollection("messageRoom")` and it's unclear what line is crashing on nil. Also, you don't need to use `DispatchQueue.main.async` within Firebase function closures are UI calls are run on the main thread.  Lastly, this `snapshot!` is dangerous as you are unsafely unwrapping an optional which will crash if it's nil (hint hint). Please protect your code and your users by safely unwrapping optionals.

Comment: @Jay I have edited the question, the earlier issue is resolved by adding "self.lastDocumentSnapshot = snapshot!.documents.last", but now I am not able to execute the "else query in func paginateData()" .  thanks for the above guidance

Comment: I formatted your code for you so it's readable. Please take the time to do that yourself going forward as crazy formatting is hard to read and may lead to the question being closed.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the formatting , I will take  care of this in future, can you please assist me the code accurate as required

Answer (score 3):

Unrelated to the question but UI calls within Firebase closures are run on the main thread so you can remove the DispatchQueue.

I don't think your code is very far off. I re-wrote it to paginate loading users 3 at a time by age and the below code works correctly.

Take a look and compare with your code. Each time this is called, it loads in the next three users.

```
var lastDocumentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot?

func observeUsersWithPagination() {
    var query: Query!

    let usersCollectionRef = self.db.collection("users")

    if let nextStartingSnap = self.lastDocumentSnapshot {
        query = usersCollectionRef.order(by: "age", descending: false).start(afterDocument: nextStartingSnap).limit(to: 3)
    } else {
        query = usersCollectionRef.order(by: "age", descending: false).limit(to: 3)
    }

    query.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        self.lastDocumentSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last

        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            let userName = diff.document.get("name") as? String ?? "No Name"
            let age = diff.document.get("age") as? Int ?? 0
            if (diff.type == .added) {
                print("Added user: \(userName)", age)
            }
            if (diff.type == .modified) {
                print("Modified user: \(userName)", age)
            }
            if (diff.type == .removed) {
                print("Removed user: \(userName)", age)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not clear if documentChanges.forEach is really needed.