# SwiftUI Firestore query cursors pagination not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to implement pagination in my app. when the app loads I want to load first item lets say. then every time he clicks refresh a new item is loaded.
I have implemented this logic in my viewmodel.

First time `homeViewModel.load()` is called in my SceneDelegate

```
let homeViewModel = HomeViewModel()
homeViewModel.refresh()
```

Then every time users wants to get new dates I call `homeViewModel.refresh()`

The problem is that when the app loads I do not get any results and when I hit refresh I keep getting the second document in the table over and over again.

What am I doing wrong here?

My HomeViewModel:

```
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject, LoadProtocol {
    var firestoreService: FirestoreService = FirestoreService()
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var first: Query = Firestore.firestore().collection("items").limit(to: 1)
    
    load() {
        self.first.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                print("Error retrieving cities: \(error.debugDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let lastSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last else {
                // The collection is empty.
                return
            }
            
            // Construct a new query starting after this document,
            // retrieving the next 25 cities.
            let next = self.db.collection("items")
                .start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot).limit(to: 1)
            
            self.first = next
            
            // Use the query for pagination.
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func refresh() {
        self.firestoreService.fetchCollection(query: self.first) { (result: Result<[Item], Error>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let items):
                self.items += items
                self.addToCategories()
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. This is suspicious `.limit(to: 1)`

Comment: well its just for testing. could be 20 but i do not have so much data

Comment: Did the solution work for you!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your refresh function

```
func refresh() {
    self.firestoreService.fetchCollection(query: self.first) { (result: Result<[Item], Error>) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let items):
            self.items += items
            self.addToCategories()
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

There's nothing in that function that advances the cursor further so it will read the same data over and over.

If you want to read the next set of data, the curser need to be moved to the last document after each refresh, like this

```
func refresh() {
    self.first.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }

        guard let lastSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last else { return }

        let next = self.db.collection("items").start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot).limit(to: 2)

        self.first = next

        for doc in snapshot.documents {
            print(doc.documentID)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, do i need to get rid of the load function then ? and use only `refresh()`?

Comment: @RexhinHoxha Not necessarily because it provides a starting point. However, I often find it easiest to maintain to just do it all in one function. Check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61439831/facing-issues-in-chat-pagination/61442720#61442720) as it rolls it all into one function - see if that gives you some ideas. Going with what I posted here would work as well with the load and then the refresh.

Comment: Thats great so the idea is to differentiate between the first query and the rest. the first should not have a  `.start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot)` right? one last thing.  addSnapshotListener will also listen to the changes made to those documents right?

Comment: This `.start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot)` is actually ok in this case because it's happening after all of the first set of documents are read in. It sets up the refresh func to start at self.first, which will be the document following the documents read in the load function.

Comment: I modified it according to your other question and its working fine! thanks

Comment: One question: `func refresh() {
        var query: Query = Firestore.firestore().collection("items").limit(to: 10)
        query.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in` Am I replacing the listener here or am I adding new listeners?

Comment: @RexhinHoxha You're adding an additional listener. The first 10 are observed and when refresh is called, it shows the next 10 and a listener is added to those as well. That allows you to handle any changes where the item falls into or out of the query - for example if an item on the prior 'page' had qty 0, and then it changes to qty 1 the app will receive a modified event for that item.